# FileNotFoundExcecption while inserting image into SDCard

Tags: android

I want to insert images into my SDCard.So I used below code

m_cImagePath = "/sdcard/"+ String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());

```
        FileOutputStream lObjOutStream = null;
        try {
            lObjOutStream = new FileOutputStream(m_cImagePath);
            if (null != lObjOutStream && null != finalBitmap) {
                finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, lObjOutStream);
                lObjOutStream.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException fe){
fe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sometimes it is giving FileNotFoundException even my SDCard had memory.When I remove some images from sdcard again it is working smoothly.Why this Happend?How can i know that file is inserted successfully in SDCard and Is there any functionality in Java1.5 to know available space of the SDCard like java 1.6?How can i know file length which is not before inserting into the SDCard(I searched in google and found that

> "when the file is not physically there
>   then file.length() always gives 0"

).But before inserting i want to know the length of the file.Then Comparing this space to available SDCard space is simple.

Note :I had an idea to use Unix command

> df sdcard

using in

> Runtime class

to found SDCard space.

Please give me an idea in this problem.

Regards,
Android Developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never never never never never hardcode `/sdcard` in an Android application. First, it's wrong on Android 2.2+. Second, it's wrong on other devices as well. Always use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for the root of external storage.

> Is there any functionality in Java1.5 to know available space of the SDCard like java 1.6?

`android.os.StatFs` has what you need.